# gallery option is not available in media upload box in costum theme option page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development

I am creating a theme in which I have to create a sponsor's image gallery on the admin panel in theme option page.

It's a slide show on the front panel. For this, I followed a tutorial to create a theme option page on using the WordPress media upload button. This will upload the images and provide a text box to save the name of the image and the jQuery code behind its functionality is as follow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#upload_logo_button').click(function() {
        tb_show('Upload a logo', 'media-upload.php?referer=wptuts-settings&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;post_id=0', false); return false;
        });
```

However, it only uploads a single image by saving its value in one single option.

Is there a way to create a gallery in media upload box and save the gallery name in one single option and I have only seen the gallery option in media box with pages/post

Comment: Take a look at [this search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+theme+development+repeatable+field) or [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Btheme+%2B%22repeatable+field%22), maybe that's what you're looking for (?)...